# Laravel storage , error creando un storage para mi NAS local

Tags: laravel, servidor, storage, almacenamiento

en mi **filesystem.php** de laravel tenogo la siguiente configuracion para mi nas :

```
'nas'=>[
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => 'http://ipNAS/directorio/',
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

Pero cuando intento guardar un fichero usando esa configuracion me da el siguiente error (**Storage::disk('nas')** :

```
Impossible to create the root directory http://ipNAS/directorio/
```

Con mi configuracion por defecto si tira (**Storage::disk('public');**) :

```
    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Comment: que so utilizas para este ejercicio, ya que hay formas mas fasiles para hacerlo una seria atravez de sftp

Comment: @Bryro pues el NAS es de la marca terramaster, usa un OS basado en linux llamado TOS

Comment: lol, me referia en donde corre tu proyecto laravel xD

Comment: @Bryro lo voy a dejar en un xamp de windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

activas la opcion de `samba` o `share` en el nass que permite compartir a windows:

luego solo necesitas crear un link simbolico desde la ventana de cmd `windows`:

## ejemplo cmd:

```
mklink /d "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\public\nube" "\\192.168.1.45\shared"
```

## ejemplo powershell

```
New-Item -Path "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\public\nube" -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value "\\192.168.1.45\shared"
```

**nota:** la carpeta `nube` en este ejemplo no debe existir ya que el la crea, se requiere ejecutar el commandline como administrador.

con esto tendrias acceso a tu servidor nass como si fuera una carpeta dentro del sistema operativo

## laravel test:

```
<img src="{{asset('nube/test.png')}}" alt="">
```

Comment: No me reconoce el comando **mklink**. Lo tengo que hacer en windows eso

Comment: en donde deseas que laravel lea la carpeta en este caso en tu windows 10

Comment: Cuando pongo mklink en cmd me dice lo siguiente : `mklink : El término 'mklink' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió 
correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.`

Comment: debes actualizar tu windows o puedes utilizar esta appicacion [Link Shell Extension](https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html) tabien puedes validar las variables de entorno y agregar las rutas esto tambien puede afectar. [video youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnO0XLCts9k)

Comment: Ya lo consegui muchas gracias